# ошибка импорта random Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
# Импорт библиотек
import random

import telebot
from telebot import types

# Импорт зависимостей
from config import TOKEN

# Импорт токена
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# keyboard
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton("ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ")
item3 = types.KeyboardButton("АВТОМАТИЗИРОВАТЬ")
item4 = types.KeyboardButton("РЕЙТИНГ МАЙНЕРОВ")

markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)


# Приветствуем пользователя
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\n Я бот созданный для мобильного иайнинга.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
    markup.add(item1)


# Импортируем список слов
# with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    # words = file.readlines()
    # words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]

# Выбираеем рандомные слова
lst = ['word_list.txt']
how_many_words = 12
(random.sample(lst, how_many_words))


# Ответы пользоателю
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'ГЕНЕРИРОВАТЬ':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.sample(lst, how_many_words)))

        elif message.text == 'ВОПРОС-ОТВЕТ':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ссылка на FAQ')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')

    # работа бота
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

и когда пытаюсь запустить код он выдает следующие ошибки

```
  File "/Users/punet/Desktop/tg bot/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    (random.sample(lst, how_many_words))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/random.py", line 482, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `(random.sample(lst, how_many_words))` - выбор 12 разных значений из списка содержащего 1 элемент в принципе невозможен. Да и вообще, в чём смысл этой строчки если результат даже не сохраняется?

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в lst содержится единственное значение 'word-list.txt', при том что Вы хотите взять 12 рандомных значений оттуда, что невозможно. Раскомментируйте код с импортированием списка слов и уберите переменную lst:

```py
Импортируем список слов
with open('word_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    words = file.readlines()
    words = [s.strip("\n") for s in words]

# Выбираеем рандомные слова
how_many_words = 12
(random.sample(words, how_many_words))
```

В таком случае, если у Вас все слова расположены в файлы в отдельных строках, программа действительно возьмёт 12 различных слов из списка. Если же в списке будет <12 строк, то выведется ошибка, указанная Вами в конца вопроса.